# How to detect collision, in 3D, between a convex volume defined by planes and a sphere

Tags: 3d, collision-detection

The method where for each plane, the sphere distance to plane is calculated and returns false if distance is greater than radius gives positive false results but also false positives.

The false positives happen when the sphere approaches a "corner" such as in a cube.

Separating axis theorem method has similar problems.

Passing all the positive false results and doing a final check by adding an axis from sphere position to closest point in the convex volume and projecting the sphere position and convex volume points on it works in 2D but I haven't managed to make it work in 3D.

This is certainly a standard problem in 3D graphics and I am hoping for a definitive answer.